# External hard disk not detected in windows, though working fine in Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Device is getting listed in the disk management in the lower panel, and showing the status as following:

- 2048 GB unallocated
- 746.52 GB unallocated

But the device is not listed in the my computer or the external storage section.

Following is the output of `"sudo fdisk -l"` on ubuntu system:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001bb17

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   617318399   308658176   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       617320446   625141759     3910657    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       617320448   625141759     3910656   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Note: sector size is 4096 (not 512)

*********** THIS IS THE EXTERNAL HARD DISK DETAILS (SEAGATE BACKUP PLUS 3TB) ***********
Disk /dev/sdc: 3000.6 GB, 3000592977920 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 45600 cylinders, total 732566645 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xfa31916b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Edit**: If possible please suggest the solution that can be implemented without loosing the data in the drive as I cannot backup the complete data elsewhere.

Comment: What exactly is your question.  Windows does not recognize the file system.  What file system is it suppose to have?

Comment: @Ramhound First of all thanks for the reply, Actually want I just want is to access the external hard disk on windows system as well, currently which is not working, though the hard disk is working fine on ubuntu system. Tried couple of option suggested in similar question but cannot try to format the drive again. Can you please suggest anything on this?

Comment: You didn't tell me what file system the disk is using, your console command, doesn't tell me either

Comment: Sorry, didn't got exactly what are you asking about, I am novice in this ares, can you please tell me how can I check the file system? Is it about the formatting type like NTFS, EXT etc.?

Comment: Yes;  NTFS is a file system.  I am trying to determine if the file system you selected is even supported by Windows.

Comment: Its showing me type as FAT (32-bit version), I guess Windows 7 can read and write drives formatted FAT32. Can you please tell what I can check next?

Comment: Change it to NTFS if you can.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Trying to check if it possible to Convert FAT32 partition to NTFS without loosing the data.

Comment: Part of the problem is you have a 3tb partition which isn't actaully a legal size for fat32

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17279/discussion-between-ankit-agrawal-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 0):

type mmc into the windows run box, hit enter.

CTRL+M add "disk management" Click ok.

Look for your drive in the list, right click it and "format drive" the drive.

Kinda looks like this

http://i.technet.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC213452.gif

Comment: Hello, thanks for looking into it, actually I am looking for the solution that can be implemented without loosing the data in the drive. One thing I am not sure is even being the FAT32 file system why windows is not able to read the content.